# robobrowser select change value

Tags: python, select, robobrowser

I'm trying to change the value for a `<select>` box from 10 to 500. Here is the HTML:

```html
    <select id="count" name="count">
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="20">20</option>
     <option value="50">50</option>
     <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
```

There is not `'500'` option listed in the form, but the web server will accept it if you alter the HTML in your browser.

My code in Python is not working:

> ```
> browser = RoboBrowser()
> browser.open(link)
>
> form = browser.get_form(action=re.compile(r'loginshop'))
> form['login'] = '/shop//loginshop.php'
> form['user'] = username
> form['pw'] = passwort
> browser.submit_form(form)
> # Search the Website
> #Suche = str(input("Suchen Sie nach einem Produkt: "))
> formSearch = browser.get_form(action=('liste.php'))
> formSearch['suche'].value = self.suche
> browser.submit_form(formSearch)
>
> #### ANZEIGEN Artikel max 500
> formSortzahl = browser.get_form(id='sort')
> formSortzahl['count'].value = '100'
> ```

i get error:
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

when i delete this:    it works.

> Sortzahl = browser.get_form(id='count')
>     formSortzahl['count'].value = '100'

Comment: Did you try `formSortzahl['count'] = '10'` yet?

Comment: Your Python code is not working because `?????` is not valid Python syntax. Can you share what you *actually* tried?

Comment: i try to browse a website with robobrowser, now i need to change the value to 500.

Comment: But 500 is not a valid option in the list.

Comment: yes but it works when you change the value. The server accept it! problem is i dont know how to change it in python with robobrowser.

Comment: you can't use anything else than what the form HTML says is valid.

Comment: i change it with google chrome elemt inspector and it works! That means you can change the value to something like 500

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean Robobrowser will let you do the same.

Comment: Looking at the robobrowser source code I can see a work-around, which I added to my answer. I also edited your question to make it clearer that you are looking to use values other than what is in the list.

Comment: I also added in a 'real' attempt at setting the value to 500. For future reference, you should really show *actual code*, preferably with the error message you get from trying that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of any select box simply by setting the `.value` attribute:

```
formSortzahl = browser.get_form(id='sort')
formSortzahl['count'].value = '100'
```

Note that you need to use a *string*; the value is validated against both the `<option>` `value` attributes and the label (the text contained in the `<option>` tag. For your sample, that means the value must be one of `'10'`, `'20'`, `'50'` or `'100'`.

You cannot easily override the options that the HTML provides, not without [mucking with the internal representation](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/blob/master/robobrowser/forms/form.py) of the form. I'd not recommend you do that.

If you really *must*, then take into account that the following code is dependent on the *current version of robobrowser*. It accesses the [`MultiOptionField.options` attribute](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/blob/master/robobrowser/forms/fields.py#L95) to add extra 'options' to the select:

```
formSortzahl['count'].options.append('500')  # include one more option
formSortzahl['count'].value = '500'
```

The attribute is not documented, so the developers of the project could still opt to change it or change the behaviour of that attribute.

Comment: formSortzahl = browser.get_form(id='sort')
        formSortzahl['count'].value = '100'                                                 Get following Error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @overView: you didn't give me enough information here; if the form is not found (no `<form id="sort">` exists) you'd get that error. In that case `browser.get_form(id='sort')` returns `None`, so the next line tries to do `None['count']` and that doesn't work.

Comment: I have had the same problem. The NoneType object error comes up when trying to run RoboBrowser.get_form() more than one time. I am not sure why this happens. It will work the first time it is called, if called a second time it will fail.